# about ng-repeat can we bind inside ng-repeat statement

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
            <button ng-click="call('d')">for d</button>
            <button ng-click="call('f')">for f</button>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in a.{{replace}}">
                    {{x}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.a = {
                    d:[1,2,3,4,5],
                    f:[6,7,8,9]
                };
                $scope.call = function(val) {
                    $scope.replace='val';
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to add dynamically the values to ng-repeat content, but it's not working, please do help
can we add dynamically values to ng-repeat itself so we can change the iterating values every time by simply changing one value like above, if not is there any better ideas

Comment: what values do you want to add on each button click?

Comment: You are not assigning passed argument, instead you are assigning string value `'val'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing strings you can pass the values in the call function then assign those values to $scope.replace which then update your ng-repeat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">       </script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
            <button ng-click="call(a.d)">for d</button>
            <button ng-click="call(a.f)">for f</button>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in replace">
                    {{x}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.a = {
                   d: [1,2,3,4,5],
                   f: [6,7,8,9]
                }
                $scope.call = function(val){
                    $scope.replace=val;}
                }
            );
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u so much sir

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet can help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <button ng-click="call('d')">for d</button>
        <button ng-click="call('f')">for f</button>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in a[replace]">
                {{x}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.a = {
                d: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                f: [6, 7, 8, 9]
            }
            $scope.call = function (val) {
                $scope.replace = val;
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Explanation :

```
$scope.replace=val; //Assign the variable and not a string

<li ng-repeat="x in a[replace]"> // No need to use braces are you are in an ng tag already
```